# How to prevent 'Packet Capture' from getting url of video play using exoplayer library in android app

Tags: java, android, security, exoplayer

I am using the `exoplayer` library in an android app to play video hosted on a server. I found that anyone can get and download video easily.

If I use a token and send as header, it can be captured by the 'Packet Capture' app.

Is there any way to prevent such data leaks.

Answer (score 1):

No.

If your data (video in your case) is hosted on a server, the server should ensure that the requesting party (your application) is correctly identified.

If this is a static identification (your token), it will always be available a way or another.

The only solution to protect such content is authentication (either of the user, or the application) but once you are authenticated and authorized to retrieve the data, you lose control over it.

The solutions which were developed to solve the problem of data in the wild are called DRM (Digital Rights Management) and are more or less effective. In any case in the simple case of your video being played by a player for everyone using your application you will not be able to protect it easily.